# Speech to Text application issue

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Ok i tried everything every single problem in every site and google even i tried every example
why I cant do speech to text in real time with google voice input ?? it works when we click on mic on the keyboard but that don't have keycode to use it in custom button to keyevent it  is there any way to do real time speech to text or implement that mic button (keycode)?

```
  private EditText log;
private SpeechRecognizer sr;
private static final String TAG = "spk2txtD2";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    log = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    //get the SpeechRecognizer and set a listener for it.
    sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    sr.setRecognitionListener(new listener());


}

@Override
public  void finish() {
    sr.destroy();
    sr = null;
    super.finish();
}
/*
 * The Recognitionlistener for the SpeechRecognizer.
 */
class listener implements RecognitionListener {
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
    }
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech(){
        Log.d(TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
    }
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB){
        Log.d(TAG, "onRmsChanged" );
    }
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBufferReceived");
    }
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onEndofSpeech");
    }
    public void onError(int error)  {
        Log.d(TAG,  "error " +  error);
        logthis("error " + error);
    }
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onResults " + results);
        // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it could have heard, there should be 5, based on the call
        ArrayList<String> matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        //display results.

       log.setText(String.valueOf(matches));
        logthis("results: "+String.valueOf(matches.size()));
        for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++) {
            Log.d(TAG, "result " + matches.get(i));
            logthis("result " +i+":"+ matches.get(i));
        }

    }
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults)
    {


        Log.d(TAG, "onPartialResults");
    }
    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onEvent " + eventType);
    }
}
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btn) {
        //get the recognize intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        //Specify the calling package to identify your application
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,getClass().getPackage().getName());
        //Given an hint to the recognizer about what the user is going to say
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        //specify the max number of results
 //       intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,0);
       intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS,true);


      //  intent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.DICTATION_MODE", true);

        //User of SpeechRecognizer to "send" the intent.
        sr.startListening(intent);
        Log.i(TAG,"Intent sent");
    }
}
/*
 * simple method to add the log TextView.
 */
public void logthis (String newinfo) {
    if (newinfo != "") {
        log.setText(log.getText() + "\n" + newinfo);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: https://github.com/ikesato/android-recognizer-intent-sample/blob/master/src/com/ikesato/recogspeech/RecogSpeechSampleActivity.java#L52  see the sample intent. Hook up any button event that u want to launch the recognizerIntent as u see in sample app.

Comment: it is not real time